# Using IF, and CountIf, in formula to return a sum of value when even with an empty cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

[image: image1]

---

[image: image2]

---

I have a spread sheet where I keep track of time. If I enter on a1 a start time b1 end time, c1 = the total time. d1,e1,f1 will be a "regular shift time". g1,h1,i1 is additional time being tracked at the end of shift.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((ISBLANK(I60))+(ISBLANK(J60)), "", J60+D60))
```

```
start   end    total    start    end    total   start    end   total    sum total
3:00    6:00    **3:00** 6:00   14:00   8:00    14:00   15:00  **1:00** **4:00**
```

My formula currently works if there is a value for each cell. But when i only have values in a,b,c it will not return a value. But it will return a value in g,h,i even if a,b,c is empty. What am i missing in this formula?

Comment: I see in your formula that your IF statement says if there are values on column I OR column J, then it will return empty  "", but if I AND J are empty, it will return J+D. Is that correct?

Comment: Also, why using array formula if you are checking specific cells instead of ranges? Where are you using your formula? It is not clear which range/cell should have it and what is your desired output

Comment: I agree with Matias. Can you provide more info and a possible example of the expected calculations output in a sample sheet?

Comment: @MatiasCG, i'm no expert with formulas, so not sure why i'm using one or the other. Trying to add a picture but not allowing me.
My columns, d,e,f, always will have a value of a shift start time. If There is any extra time done before or after we fill in the cells. 
My issue is here, if abc, & def are filled in, the sum total will not take the values of abc. The sum total will only fill if ghi have values in it.